# My ComboBox3 cannot cast the 2nd datatype to my textbox1

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello guys goodevening :D why my another datatype can't cast to the textbox1.text i dunno why he cannot cast but my other data is correct heres my codes
[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuUJH.png)

```
       private void AddEmployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillposition();
    }
//fill
    public void fillposition()
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from position", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string data = dr.GetString("EmpPosition");
            comboBox3.Items.Add(data);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

[Form did not cast the prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGm93.png)

```
    public void getposition()
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString(), out tc))
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from position 
            where EmpPosition=@EmpPosition ", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpPosition", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 
            tc;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr["Prefix"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
   private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getposition();
    }
```

Comment: int tc = 0;
        MySqlDataReader dr;

Comment: EmpPosition is written text and you try to parse it as an int, have you tried debugging your code to see what value `comboBox3.SelectedItem` in the `Int32.TryParse(` contains during runtime?

Comment: Does your program goes inside `if (Int32.TryParse....` ? Did u checked that?

Comment: the int parse tc is the combobox indexes

Comment: try this => `if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tc))`

Comment: @er-mfahhgk System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

Comment: If you meant to use the index you should use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`, which doesnt need parsing

Comment: So you have to set combobox displaymember and valuemember. ok let me add asnwer for you

Comment: ir work sir @er-mfahhgk thank you sir hehehe

Comment: my next target is auto number it from employee table if position is administrator the prefix is adm0001 if practice teacher ptr0001 it can be reliable ?

Comment: how can i commend you sir er

Comment: Better to ask another question for you next target because provding answer here to this question may cause other user or readers will get confused.

Comment: and thank you @Fixation how can i commend you too

Comment: @newb,  you can comment me by adding `@` and then my user name so this comment will be in my inbox :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Set your combo box `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` property.

```
public void fillposition()
{
    //Your code as it is
    con.Close();

    comboBox3.ValueMember = "Value";
    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Text";
}
```

2) Then use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` in below `if`

```
if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tc))
{
   //You stuff here
}
```

Comment: Did you used SelectedIndex or SelectedValue in your If condition?

Comment: i try index sir but he's read only first index when i selectedvalue he gets error but when i run lately hes working but when i rebuild my vs17 he gets error

Comment: Try ComboBox SelectedValueChanged event instead of selected index changed event and let me know

Comment: Also try this event of combobox => SelectionChangeCommitted

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

Comment: Put the code in this function "getposition" to directly  inside "SelectedValueChanged" or "SelectionChangeCommitted" event. And show me how you implemented above event at your side.

Comment: ya i put it inside the selection change commited and value change

Comment: So did u get the value of particular item that was selected by combobox?

Comment: what value sir ?

Comment: means did you get any value inside your event in `comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString()`?